# Multithreading iterative-intensive work

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, 3d

I'm creating a game with loads of asteroids floating in a huge space. To accomodate the heavy collision detection, I've split the world into "AsteroidChunks" where only the closest chunks are being used for collision detection. The work to split up the asteroids into the chunks is extremely repetitive with something like 1.2 billion iterations made every time the game starts up. However, I've noticed that the game is not actually using that much CPU power. Not a single core was running at 100%! (The game is based on MonoGame for Windows)

My idea is that by running the most iterative-heavy stuff on multiple threads (something like giving each thread 1000 iterations to complete) I would be able to get the job done quicker, at the expense of CPU power of course. Am I on the right track, and how should I proceed?

Is there any other way of speeding up the iterations, allowing for a larger 3D space?

This is what I've tried so far. It's not working, but gives an idea of what I want to accomplish: (`asteroidChunks` is a `List` with approx. 16,000 entries, but could easily be > 100,000))

```
Task[] populateChunkTasks = new Task[asteroidChunks.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < asteroidChunks.Count; i += 1000)
   populateChunkTasks[i] = new Task(() =>
    {
        for (int x = i; x < asteroidChunks.Count && x < i + 1000; x++)
            PopulateChunk(asteroidChunks[x]);
    });

for (int i = 0; i < populateChunkTasks.Length; i++)
    populateChunkTasks[i].Start();

Task.WaitAll(populateChunkTasks);
```

As you can see I want to wait for the threads to complete at the end. However, the operation itself is in its own `Task`, which is why I can't wait for all tasks - in this case - to complete before proceeding.

`PopulateChunk`: (`asteroidList` is a list with approx 75,000 entries, but could easily be > 1million)

```
public static AsteroidChunk PopulateChunk(AsteroidChunk chunk)
{
    foreach (Asteroid asteroid in asteroidList)
        if (chunk.box.Contains(asteroid.boundingSphere) == ContainmentType.Contains)
            chunk.asteroids.Add(asteroid);

    return chunk;
}
```

Comment: asteroidChunks.AsParallel().FoAll(PopulateChunk);

Comment: There are *many* games. Most games use a *single thread* for collision detection/physics. Follow suit: don't use multiple threads, use a better scheme for collision detection .. even *when* using threading, the number of threads that can improve performance is 1-2x the number of cores (depending on scheduling etc), which is *much less* than 1000. Getting the job done quicker *cannot* be at the [overall] expense of CPU power.

Comment: Your problem is that you're using a horrible algorithm to do the work. I don't do any game dev, so experts can chime in, but some kind of space partitioning algorithm is probably called for. [Quad trees](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) come to mind (well octo tree I guess).

Comment: You can always use Amdahl's law (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) to calculate theoretical improvement in performence for multithreaded solution.

Comment: You should first focus on an adequate algorithm for spatial partitioning (e.g. octree) that gives you a complexity of O(n*log(n)) for collision detection. Then you could concentrate on how to parallelize that structure, which might not be necessary anymore.

Comment: I see that a lot of the comments end up about the collission detection. To clarify: the collission detection is a bottleneck for me, but not the problem. My problem is that the code that makes sure that collission detection will work LATER on (this code is NOT collission detection!) takes a long time to execute since it does not utilize the availible resources properly. I want the above code to execute quicker and running the cpu at 100% would actually be a pretty good thing in this case. This code needs only to be executed once, when the game is started, not multiple times.

Comment: You misunderstand the comments or linked algorithms. Quad trees also tell you how to pre process the data in a more efficient way than O(n^2). Parallelization at best gives you linear speed ups in line with core count - that won't do you much good with your quadratic algorithm.

Comment: Or to make it more intuitive, your algorithm is O(n^2) while a naive octo tree algorithm is O(n log n) (and it has some other advantages which make the constants look better). Say you have 10^5 nodes, your algorithm would need on the order of 10^10 operations, while the other one world need about 10^6 operations (yes people I know I'm horribly abusing big O notation here, run with it). That's about 10^4 times more work. Paralellizing your code assuming 100 cores would mean every thread would have to do 10^8 operations or still about 100 times more work.